# How to model relationship when using Power BI for simple use-case of source data mapping?

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling

I have 4 tables.

Data: ID, Name, Region, Location, Company

Region: Region, RegionCode

Location: Location, LocationCode

Company: Company, CompanyCode

I need to create a table visual, and add all fields from the data table into this visual. And then I need to pull the respective Code values from the other table. Effectively the table visual will have following columns:

ID, Name, Region, Location, Company, RegionCode, LocationCode, CompanyCode.

I have imported all the tables into Power BI. Now I am working on the model and trying to understand whether the data table must be placed at the center with the other tables filtering into (direction of filter from other tables into the data table) the data table?

Or do I make the data table filter (direction of filter from data table into other tables) other tables?